# Targeting itemprop in CSS

Tags: html, css, joomla, css-selectors

Using the custom.css code below, I’m succesfully overridding the css files of a commercial Joomla 3 Template.

```
div[itemprop="articleBody"] h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
     margin-top: 18px!important;
     margin-bottom: 0px!important;
}
```

The custom.css should apply  to:

```
<div itemprop="articleBody">
   <h1><strong>Some Text</strong></h1>
   <p> Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text </p>
</div>
```

The problem is that the custom.css code is applied even to h tags outside the `<div itemprop="articleBody">` container in all major browsers.

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Writing

```
div[itemprop="articleBody"] h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 margin-top: 18px!important;
 margin-bottom: 0px!important;
}
```

You set styles first to the `h1` that is inside `div` with itemprop, but then you add styles to all `h2,h3,h4,h5,h6` that are on the whole page.

So the problem is that you don't write CSS selectors properly.
You need to add a parent selector for every heading, for example

```
div[itemprop="articleBody"] h1,
div[itemprop="articleBody"] h2,
div[itemprop="articleBody"] h3{
    /*styles*/
}
```

OR if you use a CSS preprocessor like SASS or LESS

```
div[itemprop="articleBody"] {
   h1 { }
   h2 { }
   h3 { }
   ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must select the itemprop attribute for each headline definition. Rewrite the style definition as follows

```
div[itemprop="articleBody"] h1, div[itemprop="articleBody"] h2, 
div[itemprop="articleBody"] h3, div[itemprop="articleBody"] h4, 
div[itemprop="articleBody"] h5, div[itemprop="articleBody"] h6 {
     margin-top: 18px!important;
     margin-bottom: 0px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the very first phase you have to put h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 tag inside div element. otherwise if you just put the h1, h2 tag ad write some css without div element then it will override all the css. so you should use the parent selector i.e is div element

```css
div[itemprop="articleBody"] h1, div[itemprop="articleBody"] h2, div[itemprop="articleBody"] h3, div[itemprop="articleBody"] h4, div[itemprop="articleBody"] h5, div[itemprop="articleBody"] h6 {
 margin-top: 18px!important;
 margin-bottom: 0px!important;
}
```

```html
<div itemprop="articleBody">
   <h1><strong>Some Text</strong></h1>
   <p> Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text </p>
</div>
```